# How do I collect elements with Beautiful Soup?

Tags: python, web, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to make a web scraper with beautiful soup but every time I try scrape the website I dont get anything back. In the following code I use requests to fetch the website then I  put it into the beautiful soup object. After that I try to scrape for all the  tags.

Ive tried watching youtube tutorials and looked at the documentation for the framework but i just dont understand how to use it.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import bs4
import urllib

url = requests.get("https://www.rt.com/")

print(url.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

soup.find_all('div')
```

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the `requests` package and you are not doing anything with the results.

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

url = requests.get("https://www.rt.com/")

print(url.status_code)

soup = BeautifulSoup(url.content, 'html.parser')

divs = soup.find_all('div') # save results to a variable

# Print the text inside each div (example of how to use the results)
for div in divs:
    print(div.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all your code doesn't work at this moment as you forgot to import requests package. So once you import the package it will work.

Secondly I would recommend to read BeautifulSoup [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/) thoroughly. It has all answers you need. So if you need all anchors on that page just assign them to a variable like here:

```
 elems = soup.find_all('a')
```

after that you can work with it as with set of results, so if you need to extract links from anchor elements you can do following:

```
for link in elems:
    print(link.get('href'))

# http://example.com/elsie
# http://example.com/lacie
# http://example.com/tillie
```